# cx_Freeze and win32ui - ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, python-2.7, dll, cx-freeze, pywin32

I'm trying to build an exe with cx_Freeze.

It worked before but since I have imported win32ui in my Python program, I get this error when running the created exe file:

[image: error]

I double checked, the following line is the cause:

```
import win32ui
```

Importing win32print works fine though.

I'm using Python 2.7 and PyWin32 build 220

Comment: Can you post your build script to provide more details

Comment: Sure: https://ghostbin.com/paste/oyon4

Comment: I am getting similar issue. importing win32ui throwing exception of ImportError

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as described, the solution was to include the pythonwin folder in the environment path. More specifically the mfc140u.dll is required to ensure that win32ui.pyd imports correctly.

Solution inspired from the [Python Mail list](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2012-July/012439.html)